# What is the difference between the client and server counters in Squid?

Tags: squid

We have a Squid instance running at the company, and 
 I understand I can get a lot of metrics out of Squid by using the Squidclient. 
For instance if I run:
`squidclient -h localhost -p xxxx cache_object://localhost/ mgr:utilization | grep -P "http.kbytes" | sort`
I get the following output:

`client_http.kbytes_in = 0.000278/sec
client_http.kbytes_in = 0.001111/sec
client_http.kbytes_in = 0.003333/sec
client_http.kbytes_in = 1
client_http.kbytes_out = 0.015833/sec
client_http.kbytes_out = 0.063333/sec
client_http.kbytes_out = 0.190000/sec
client_http.kbytes_out = 57
server.http.kbytes_in = 0
server.http.kbytes_in = 0.000000/sec
server.http.kbytes_in = 0.000000/sec
server.http.kbytes_in = 0.000000/sec
server.http.kbytes_out = 0
server.http.kbytes_out = 0.000000/sec
server.http.kbytes_out = 0.000000/sec
server.http.kbytes_out = 0.000000/sec`

Do the client counters reflect the traffic between me and the Squid instance and the server counters reflect the traffic between the Squid instance and the internet?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

> Do the client counters reflect the traffic between me and the Squid instance and the server counters reflect the traffic between the Squid instance and the internet?

Assuming you are the only user of that proxy and that it is only ever connecting to the Internet, that would be a yes.

That is a bad assumption though. Server could be anywhere, including within the LAN. Clients could be anywhere, including on the Internet.

To be precise:

- the client counters are for traffic to and from any clients that have contacted the proxy. Note that this only requires contact - regardless of whether they were allowed to use it. Bandwidth used rejecting non-allowed clients is also included in these counters.
- the server counters are for any server or peer that the proxy has contacted.